# How would i convert this eight ball script to ruby

Tags: ruby

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var answers = new Array(
"Yes.",
"No.", 
"My sources are pointing toward yes.", 
"It's possible.",
"Very unlikely.", 
"Can you repeat the question?",
"Absolutely not.", 
"Sure.",
"Ask again later."
);
function fortune() {
num = Math.round( (answers.length - 1) * Math.random());
return answers[num];
}
//  End -->
</script>
```

then when i call `fortune('text')` it gets a value from the array

Comment: google "hire a freelancer", or, *what have you tried?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fortune
  ["Yes.",
   "No.", 
   "My sources are pointing toward yes.", 
   "It's possible.",
   "Very unlikely.", 
   "Can you repeat the question?",
   "Absolutely not.", 
   "Sure.",
   "Ask again later."].sample
end
```

Comment: Better to use a constant. This way you create the same array over and over again. Still it works :)